# MayaVi - Anaconda - Windows 8 - Graphical Dependencies

Tags: python, qt, vtk, mayavi

I've been struggling to get MayaVi working on Windows for quite some time now and so I turn to the internet. I am using the Anaconda distribution and I just did a conda update on everything yesterday, so presumably it is up to do date. Futhermore, I have installed VTK (both the QT and PySide? versions) from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Here is my awesome test code:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

x = np.linspace(0,NX,1)
y = np.linspace(0,NY,1)
z = np.linspace(0,NZ,1)

xs,ys,zs = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)

plot = xs
mlab.pipeline.volume(mlab.pipeline.scalar_fields(plot))
mlab.show()
```

When I run it from a command line ( D:\directory> python testfile ), I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dipole_trap_interference", line 13, in <module>
    from mayavi import mlab
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mayavi\mlab.py", line 27, in <module>
    from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\camera.py", line 25, in <modu
le>
    from engine_manager import get_engine
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 14,
in <module>
    from mayavi.core.engine import Engine
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\engine.py", line 12, in <modul
e>
    import vtk
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\vtk\__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    from qvtk import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\vtk\qvtk.py", line 8, in <module>
    from QVTKPython import *
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v10.0 to v10.1 but the vtk.QVTKPytho
n module requires API v11.0
```

From an iPython console, we can see a little more detail:

```
In [2]: import vtk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b7e11aadda62> in <module>()
----> 1 import vtk

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\vtk\__init__.py in <module>()
    133
    134 try:
--> 135     from qvtk import *
    136     kits.append('qvtk')
    137 except ImportError, exc:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\vtk\qvtk.py in <module>()
      6
      7 # library for Qt classes with VTK support
----> 8 from QVTKPython import *

RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v10.0 to v10.1 but the vtk.QVTKPytho
n module requires API v11.0
```

A quick google search for that error comes up with http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/481052-Python-vtk-problem. So I have to install a newer python-sip. BUT, I already have the latest PyQt4... doesn't this come bundled with the latest python-sip? Also in matplotlib.rc I have

```
backend      : Qt4Agg
backend.qt4 : PyQt4        # PyQt4 | PySide
```

very confusing.

Comment: You are using a very old, pyqt... you should try pyqt5 out.

Comment: VTK-Qt4-5.10.1 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#vtk requires PyQt4-4.10.4/Qt4.8.6 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt